# How to add application.conf files for akka multi-jvm applications

Tags: scala, akka

I have created a set of applications in akka in the multi-jvm. Following all the conventions on the docs http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/dev/multi-jvm-testing.html I can run them using multi-jvm:run {application name}.

This behaves perfectly but the applications now require remote akka features. To do this I need to change settings in application.conf as mentioned here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html

My problem is that I do not now how to give each of these multi-jvm test applications an application.conf file of their own. I'm not sure if their is a file-system based convention, or it has to be done in code. Either solution would solve the problem in theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you define the configuration in code in the test using ConfigFactory.parseString and use that in MultiNodeConfig.commonConfig.
Note that you can use define specific config per node with MultiNodeConfig.nodeConfig.

Answer (score 0):

The application.conf's are loaded from the class path, but you can override them with system properties as described here: https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior

So for each JVM, you can specify the necessary System properties(which is kind of ugly), or you can drop an application.conf in the classpath of each JVM that overrides the reference.conf's in the libraries.